# What is the Python way for recursively setting file permissions?

Tags: python, recursion, chown

What's the "python way" to recursively set the owner and group to files in a directory? I could just pass a 'chown -R' command to shell, but I feel like I'm missing something obvious.

I'm mucking about with this:

```
import os  
path = "/tmp/foo"  
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):  
  for momo in dirs:  
    os.chown(momo, 502, 20)
```

This seems to work for setting the directory, but fails when applied to files. I suspect the files are not getting the whole path, so chown fails since it can't find the files. The error is:

'OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'foo.html'

What am I overlooking here?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The `dirs` and `files` lists are all always relative to `root` - i.e., they are the `basename()` of the files/folders, i.e. they don't have a `/` in them (or `\` on windows). You need to join the dirs/files to `root` to get their whole path if you want your code to work to infinite levels of recursion:

```
import os  
path = "/tmp/foo"
    
# Change permissions for the top-level folder
os.chmod(path, 502, 20)

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
  # set perms on sub-directories  
  for momo in dirs:
    os.chown(os.path.join(root, momo), 502, 20)

  # set perms on files
  for momo in files:
    os.chown(os.path.join(root, momo), 502, 20)
```

Surprisingly, the `shutil` module doesn't have a function for this.

Comment: This has a bug which I just saw in my co-worker's code in production :-) The top level directory specified is not being chowned. I suggested an edit with a fix, hopefully it gets approved.

Comment: So my edit was rejected - good look to anyone who uses this and encounters the  bug where `/tmp/foo` does NOT have its permissions changed. Good job moderating SO pythonians 

Comment: @AvindraGoolcharan good catch - hopefully that was what you had in mind!

Comment: No need to loop through `dirs` since `os.walk` will go through all directories anyway. See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57458550/100217).

Comment: @AvindraGoolcharan Edits [1](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13116851), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11851085), strike [3](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11715569) you're out. Apparently 9 reviewers think adding `os.chown(path, 502, 20)` "deviates from intent", "should be a comment", or "is worth making a whole new answer for". Really...? One line? Do all these people not know that `chmod -R some_dir` would change `some_dir` and all its child directories? I know you all are terrified about approving code edits, but still, this is silly

Comment: @AvindraGoolcharan, good catch! It's a shame your edit was rejected. Now even Copilot will suggest this snippet ...

Comment: @Leo thanks for the heads up. I added the fix and the comment. FWIW, GPT-4 suggests the original answer. After suggesting "Does this also change the permissions on the top-level (root) folder?" ChatGPT makes the correct edit to change the perms on the root folder.

Answer (score 31):

As correctly pointed out above, the accepted answer misses top-level files and directories. The other answers use `os.walk` then loop through `dirnames` and `filenames`. However, `os.walk` goes through `dirnames` anyway, so you can skip looping through `dirnames` and just `chown` the current directory (`dirpath`):

```
def recursive_chown(path, owner):
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(path):
        shutil.chown(dirpath, owner)
        for filename in filenames:
            shutil.chown(os.path.join(dirpath, filename), owner)
```

Comment: Why shutil.chown instead of os.chown?

Comment: @gerardw I believe os.chown() only takes numeric uid and gid, whereas shutil.chown() will accept names or numeric IDs.

Answer (score 19):

> I could just pass a 'chown -R' command to shell

This is the simplest way, and gets lost in the question a bit, so just for clarity, you can do this in one line if you don't care about Windows:

```
os.system('chown -R 502 /tmp/foo')
```

Comment: This doesn't get enough credit. It would be nice for shutil to gain the recursive functionality, but until then, why bother..

Answer (score 8):

```
import os  
path = "/tmp/foo"  
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):  
  for momo in dirs:  
    os.chown(momo, 502, 20)
  for file in files:
     fname = os.path.join(root, file)
     os.chown(fname, aaa, bb)
```

substitute `aaa` and `bb` as you please

Comment: As in the accepted comment, `/tmp/foo` will NOT have the owner properly set. See my comments above.

Answer (score 4):

try `os.path.join(root,momo)` that will give you full path

Answer (score 2):

Here is a function i wrote that uses glob to recursively list files and change their permissions.

```
import os
import glob
def recursive_file_permissions(path,mode,uid=-1,gid=-1):
        '''
        Recursively updates file permissions on a given path.
        UID and GID default to -1, and mode is required
        '''
    for item in glob.glob(path+'/*'):
        if os.path.isdir(item):
            recursive_file_permissions(os.path.join(path,item),mode,uid,gid)
        else:
            try:
                os.chown(os.path.join(path,item),uid,gid)
                os.chmod(os.path.join(path,item),mode)
            except:
                print('File permissions on {0} not updated due to error.'.format(os.path.join(path,item)))
```

it's not perfect, but got me where I needed to be

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer misses top level files. This is the actual equivalent of `chown -R`.

```
import os

path = "/tmp/foo"

os.chown(path, 502, 20)
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(path):
    for dname in dirnames:
        os.chown(os.path.join(dirpath, dname), 502, 20)
    for fname in filenames:
        os.chown(os.path.join(dirpath, fname), 502, 20)
```

Comment: No need to loop through `dirnames` since `os.walk` will go through all directories anyway. See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57458550/100217).

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget the `for f in files` loop, either.  Similarly, remember to `os.path.join(root, f)` to get the full path.

Answer (score 0):

```
"""
Requires python 3
Accepts name or id
Usage:
  chown.py -p /temp/folder -u user  -g group -r true
  or
  chown.py -p /temp/folder -u uid -g gid -r 1
  user, group, and recursive are optional
  But must supply at least one of user or group
Example: sudo chown.py -p /temp/filename -u some_user 
"""
import argparse, os, sys
from shutil import chown
user = group = recursive = ''
parser=argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-p', '--path')  # help='file/path'
parser.add_argument('-u', '--user')   # , help='user'
parser.add_argument( '-g','--group')   # , help='group'
parser.add_argument('-r', '--recursive', help=1)  # , help='recursive'

args=parser.parse_args()
path = args.path
if not path:
    raise Exception('missing path')
if args.user:
    user = args.user
if args.group:
    user = args.group
if args.recursive:
    recursive = True

if not user and not group:
    raise Exception('must supply user, group, or both')

def change_owner(path, user='', group='')
    if user and not group:
        chown(path, user=user)
    elif not user and group:
        chown(path, group=group)
    else:
        chown(path, user, group)

change_owner(path, user, group)
if recursive:
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(path):
        for dname in dirnames:
            change_owner(os.path.join(dirpath, dname), user, group)
        for fname in filenames:
            change_owner(os.path.join(dirpath, fname), user, group)
```

Answer (score -2):

use `os.lchown` instead of `os.chown` for *changing link themselves* and files together.