# How can I remove all write permissions from a directory with python recursivly

Tags: python, file-permissions

I want to remove all write permissions from a directory and all it's sub-directories and files with python

I want something like this:

```
os.chmod(path, "a-w", recursive=True)
```

In bash it would be this:

```
chmod -R a-w $path
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use `subprocess` module. Your code will look like that:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call(['chmod', '-R', 'a-w', path])
```

For `os`-based solution see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2853723/what-is-the-python-way-for-recursively-setting-file-permissions).

Answer (score 1):

```
import subprocess

try:
    subprocess.check_call(["chmod -R a-w {path}".format(path=path)], shell=True) # Or  subprocess.check_call(["chmod", "-R", "a-w", path])
except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
    pass # handle errors in the called executable
except OSError:
    pass # executable not found
```