# What is the equivalent of "chmod -R u+x $path" in Python?

Tags: python, bash

What's the equivalent of this bash command in Python?

`chmod -R u+x $dir_path`

There is `os.fchmod` but not sure if it applies recursively as the original command does.

Does this do the same thing that I want?

```
import os
import stat
from pathlib import Path

fd = Path(dir_path).open().fileno()
os.fchmod(fd, stat.S_IXUSR)
```

Comment: Perhaps `os.walk(path)` and then `os.chmod()` each file individually. No need to use the `os.fchmod(fd)` variant which requires a file handle. Of course, you could always use `os.system()` to run chmod.

Comment: duplicate (?) of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2853723/what-is-the-python-way-for-recursively-setting-file-permissions

Comment: @Demi-Lune almost the same, though that question relates to file ownership.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`os.chmod`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_chmod.htm) but that'll only change permissions of that individual file or directory.  To change permissions of a single file incrementally (by adding to the existing permissions), use:

```
import os
import stat

st = os.stat("path/to/file")
os.chmod("/path/to/file", st.st_mode | stat.S_IXUSR)
```

Now, to change permissions of files in a directory recursively, you would need to use [`os.walk`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_walk.htm) to traverse through all sub directories and their files:

```
import os
import stat

for root, dirs, files in os.walk("path/to/directory"):
    for name in dirs:
        path = os.path.join(root, name)
        st = os.stat(path)
        os.chmod(path, st.st_mode | stat.S_IXUSR)
    for name in files:
        path = os.path.join(root, name)
        st = os.stat(path)
        os.chmod(path, st.st_mode | stat.S_IXUSR)
```

The above will both traverse subdirectories and will incrementally modify permissions only to add user execution permissions.

There are other alternatives, one fun and obvious one is:

```
os.system("chmod -R u+x /path/to/file")
```

For future reference, here are two related questions:

- [How to use Python's `os.chmod` recursively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7187200/chmod-recursively-directories-only)
- [How to do `chmod +x` using Python's `os.chmod`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12791997/how-do-you-do-a-simple-chmod-x-from-within-python)